# How to know which callable finished upon pool method in CompletionService in java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, completion-service

Let say you are writing a code like following:

```
CompletionService<T> completion = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(new ExecutorService());

for(Callable callable : callableList) {
    completion.submit(callable);
}

// Do something else

while(true) {
    Future<T> future = completion.poll();

    // At this point, is there a way to find out which callable is returning this future?
}
```

If you see the code above, is there a way to find out which callable is returned at the time I call completion.poll and have future in return?

I can extend Callable to have some kind of ID to do that, but I want to find out if it is possible by java itself generically.

Comment: Callable, like Runnable, is a very simple interface. It does not contain identifier data.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: Although there may be some intrusive way of doing so (i.e. reflection), the `Future` returned by the `ExecutionCompletionService.poll()` method does not expose the `Callable` that was completed.

---

Looking at the JDK 9 source for `ExecutionCompletionService.submit(Callable)`, the submitted `Callable` is wrapped in a `RunnableFuture` (whose actual type is `FutureTask` if we look into `newTaskFor(Callable)`):

```
public Future<V> submit(Callable<V> task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<V> f = newTaskFor(task);
    executor.execute(new QueueingFuture<V>(f, completionQueue));
    return f;
}

private RunnableFuture<V> newTaskFor(Callable<V> task) {
    if (aes == null)
        return new FutureTask<V>(task);
    else
        return aes.newTaskFor(task);
}
```

Even if `aes.newTaskFor(task)` is called, where `aes` is an `AbstractExecutorService`, the result is a `FutureTask`:

```
public abstract class AbstractExecutorService implements ExecutorService {

    // ...

    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new FutureTask<T>(callable);
    }
}
```

If we look into the `QueueingFuture` inner class, we see the following definition:

```
private static class QueueingFuture<V> extends FutureTask<Void> {
    QueueingFuture(RunnableFuture<V> task,
                   BlockingQueue<Future<V>> completionQueue) {
        super(task, null);
        this.task = task;
        this.completionQueue = completionQueue;
    }
    private final Future<V> task;
    private final BlockingQueue<Future<V>> completionQueue;
    protected void done() { completionQueue.add(task); }
}
```

The `completionQueue` passed to the newly created `QueueingFuture` in the `submit` method is a `BlockingQueue<Future<T>>` that stores the stores the `Future` objects that correspond to the completed `Callable` objects supplied to `submit`. Stated differently, once a `Callable` submitted to `ExecutorCompletionService` using the `submit` method is finished executing, the `Future` that corresponds to that submitted `Callable` is enqueued in `completionQueue`. The `ExecutionCompletionService.poll()` method simply delegates to a poll on the `completionQueue`:

```
public Future<V> poll() {
    return completionQueue.poll();
}
```

Thus, the only way we could obtain a reference to the original `Callable` is to obtain it from the `Future` object returned from `ExecutionCompletionService.poll()` (your original question). But, looking at the `Future` interface, there does not exist a method that exposes any `Callable`:

```
public interface Future<V> {
    boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning);
    boolean isCancelled();
    boolean isDone();
    V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException;
    V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException;
}
```

Even the `FutureTask` (the implementation type returned from `ExecutionCompletionService.poll()`) does not expose its internal `Callable`:

```
public class FutureTask<V> implements RunnableFuture<V> {

    private Callable<V> callable;

    public FutureTask(Callable<V> callable) {
        if (callable == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.callable = callable;
        // ...
    }
}
```

If `FutureTask` had some method exposing the underlying `Callable`, then we may be able to make an explicit cast to `FutureTask`, but since it does not, that route would not solve the problem at hand.

The issue here is that we are trying to combine synchronous code with an asynchronous `ExecutionCompletionService`. One way to solve this issue in a synchronized manner would be to return the ID of the `Callable` when it completes so that calling `Future.get()` on the `Future` returned from `ExecutionCompletionService.poll()` returns the ID (as you mentioned). Then the ID can be paired to its original `Callable`. An asynchronous approach would be to register a callback with the original `Callable` that is called when the `Callable` completes.

Hopefully the explanation was more helpful than a simple *no*.